# Horizontal positioning with unknown width (and small parent element)

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create simple tooltip in CSS3.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cg2SX/

Example HTML (can be changed if necessary):

```
    <div class="icons">
        <a href="">t <span class="tooltip">Twitter</span></a>
        <a href="">f <span class="tooltip">Facebook</span></a>
        <a href="">g <span class="tooltip">Google+</span></a>
    </div>​
```

And CSS:

```
    .icons { position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 30px; }
    .icons a { text-decoration:none; font-size: 16px; color: #000000; position: relative; margin-right: 70px; border:1px solid red; }
    .icons a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
    .tooltip { background-color: green; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 10px; padding: 2px 8px; bottom: -20px; position: absolute; }​
```

The problem is - I have no idea how to center tooltips below sharing icons (they will be font icons). It wouldn't be complicated if I knew their width but I don't.

Any ideas appreciated. Is it possible anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try doing it like this:

## [*updated fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/Cg2SX/4/)

Using a fixed (big enough) `width` on the `span`, setting `text-align: center` on it & putting the text in a pseudo-element to which you give `display: inline-block`

**HTML**:

```
<div class="icons">
    <a href="#">t
        <span class="tooltip" data-text='Twitter'></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">f
        <span class="tooltip" data-text="Facebook"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">g
        <span class="tooltip" data-text='Google+'></span>
    </a>
</div>​
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.icons a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 70px;
    width: 16px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px; left: 8px; /* half the width of link */
    margin-left: -35px;
    width: 70px;
    color: #fff;
    font: 10px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.tooltip:after {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    background-color: green;
    content: attr(data-text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cg2SX/1/

I updated `a` tags then inside `.icons` div. Here's what I **changed**:

```
.icons a {
    display:block;
    margin-right:10px /* spacing between a tags - changed from your original code */
    float:left; 
    text-align:center; 
    width:100px; /* you can change this as needed, but it keeps them all uniform*/
    height: 50px; /* Change this to the height of your tallest icon image */
}
```

Then I update the `span.tooltip` accordingly, I **added** this to what you had:

```
.tooltip { 
    width:100%;
    padding: 2px 0; /* changed the side padding to 0 since width is 100% & it takes the text-align center from the CSS above on the a tag */
    display:block; /* Made it a block so the width 100% & centered text would work */
}​
```

This doesn't matter on the exact size of your icon images - they could all be different or the same, but as long as the over `a` tags are wider and taller than the tallest and widest image, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Yes, but it's fixed width. I need a solution where tooltip can be of unlimited width.

Comment: Well do it this way then: http://jsfiddle.net/Cg2SX/2/   - The width is stil fixed, but height is unlimited. It looks like this is only for social media icons, so I guess I'm confused why you need so much width/height to begin with?

Comment: Yes, but I mean - I need text to fit rectangle without additional pixels other than padding :) So, my initial question was how to center container with unknown width in another with small width. Thanks for your examples though!

Comment: What's the tooltip JS you're using? Some JS/jQuery will do centering for you on tooltips...

Comment: I want it to be CSS3 only solution - I know it's possible but I can't figure it out so far.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you work with => width:auto;